# set left handed mouse, then wacom stylus buttons switch too

Tags: mouse, lubuntu, wacom

I'm using Lubuntu 12.04. I can set my mouse (basic usb mouse) to left hand (i.e. switch the left and right mouse buttons which is all I need) by going into Preferences / Keyboard and Mouse.

However, it changes my Wacom stylus, so that when the tip touches the tablet it acts like the right mouse button, making it impossible to draw.

Is there a way to have both happen at once? The stylus buttons working in right handed configuration, while the mouse works in left handed configuration?

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I found the solution.

After you switch to left handed button (in preferences > mouse) you must execute this in the terminal to map the touchpad taps correctly

```
manolo@manolo-TravelMate-5720:~$ synclient TapButton1=3
manolo@manolo-TravelMate-5720:~$ synclient TapButton2=1
```

Now just program those lines to execute this every time Lubuntu starts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. These are the settings I used:

```
button and feedback        tablet  
stylus: right hand         left hand  
same settings for eraser  
finger and touch both set to left hand
```

It seems to be working fine. I tested it in Gimp and Mypaint. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: That looks intriguing - I'd like to try it, but I'm not entirely sure how you did it? Via the command line, or...? Unfortunately I'm using an old Windows graphic program (Creature House Expression) under Wine, so Gimp-specific settings don't work for me.

Comment: i used the default settings manager and then go to mouse and touchpad find your wacom devices and use the above settings

Comment: Darn. I'm using Lubuntu, which doesn't include those settings.